# X3: How to create parser to read in sets?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

How would one create a rule for reading integers in sets of 3. I.e., ...

```
1 2 3                   OK, 1 set of 3 ints
1 2 3 4 5 6             OK, 2 sets of 3 ints
1 2 3 4 5               ERROR, 1 set of 3 ints, 1 short for 2nd
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9       OK, 3 sets of 3 ints
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10    ERROR, 3 sets of 3 ints, 1 short for 4th
```

I'm having issue with the fusion adapt struct (how to make the number of args variable) ...

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::number, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6)
```

And not sure why this rule wouldn't work.

```
... = *(int_ >> int_ >> int_);
```

Here's my attempt ...
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb10e8096c95fc55

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

namespace client { 
    namespace ast {

        struct number {
            int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6;
        };

        struct comment {
            std::string text;
            bool dummy;
        };

        struct input {
            std::vector<comment> comments;  
            std::vector<number> numbers;
        };
    } 
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::comment, text, dummy)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::number, n1, n2, n3) // , n4, n5, n6) error
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::input, comments, numbers)

namespace client {      
    namespace parser {

        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
        using namespace x3;

        typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

        using namespace x3;

        auto const comment = rule<struct _c, ast::comment> {"comment"} = lexeme[*(char_ - eol)] >> attr(false);
        auto const number  = rule<struct _n, ast::number> {"number"}   = int_ >> int_ >> int_;
        // auto const number  = rule<struct _n, ast::number> {"number"}   = *(int_ >> int_ >> int_); error

        auto lines = [](auto p) { return *(p >> eol); };

        auto const input = 
            repeat(1)[comment] >> eol >>
            lines(number);
    }
}

int main() {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    std::string const iss("any char string here\n1 2 3\n1 2 3 4 5 6");

    auto iter = iss.begin(), eof = iss.end();

    client::ast::input types;

    bool ok = phrase_parse(iter, eof, client::parser::input, x3::blank, types);

    if (iter != eof) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(iter, eof) << "'\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Parsed: " << (100.0 * std::distance(iss.begin(), iter) / iss.size()) << "%\n";
    std::cout << "ok = " << ok << std::endl;

    for (auto& item : types.comments) { std::cout << "comment: " << boost::fusion::as_deque(item) << "\n"; }
    for (auto& item : types.numbers)  { std::cout << "number:  " << boost::fusion::as_deque(item) << "\n"; }
}
```

Printing

```
Parsed: 71.0526%
ok = 1
comment: (any char string here 0)
number:  (1 2 3)
```

Comment: I failed to compile your code - so I cannot verify my suspisions - but I think the problem lies in the input definition. Your input did not split all [number] chunks into separate lines so you need something like         auto const input = 
            repeate(1)[comment] >> eol >>
            repeat[number];
But I do not know how to prevent reading the number from across 2 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator Kleene-star synthesizes into a container attribute (docs show: `vector<T>`)

Your struct `number` is not a container attribute. So.

Also, it's completely unclear to me what you want to achieve. Your struct is supposedly 6 ints, but you want to parse groups of 3? What is the *meaning* of the groups? I'd probably do:

```
struct number {
    struct group { int n1, n2, n3; };
    std::vector<group> groups;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::number::group, n1, n2, n3)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::number, groups)
```

This then is compatible with the parser expression

```
 *(int_ >> int_ >> int_)
```

### Live Demo

Two notes:

1. the dummy attibrute was needed again (consider `using number = std::vector<number_group>;`)
2. there was a missing `\n` at the end of input (consider `eol | eoi`)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07c176a99c2d5371)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

namespace client { 
    namespace ast {

        struct number {
            struct group { int n1, n2, n3; };
            std::vector<group> groups;
            bool dummy;
        };

        struct comment {
            std::string text;
            bool dummy;
        };

        struct input {
            std::vector<comment> comments;  
            std::vector<number> numbers;
        };
    } 
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::comment, text, dummy)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::number::group, n1, n2, n3)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::number, groups, dummy)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::input, comments, numbers)

namespace client {      
    namespace parser {

        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
        using namespace x3;

        typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

        using namespace x3;

        auto const comment = rule<struct _c, ast::comment> {"comment"} = lexeme[*(char_ - eol)] >> attr(false);
        auto const number  = rule<struct _n, ast::number> {"number"}   = *(int_ >> int_ >> int_) >> attr(false);

        auto lines = [](auto p) { return *(p >> eol); };

        auto const input = 
            repeat(1)[comment] >> eol >>
            lines(number);
    }
}

int main() {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    std::string const iss("any char string here\n1 2 3\n1 2 3 4 5 6\n");

    auto iter = iss.begin(), eof = iss.end();

    client::ast::input types;

    bool ok = phrase_parse(iter, eof, client::parser::input, x3::blank, types);

    if (iter != eof) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(iter, eof) << "'\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Parsed: " << (100.0 * std::distance(iss.begin(), iter) / iss.size()) << "%\n";
    std::cout << "ok = " << ok << std::endl;

    for (auto &item : types.comments) {
        std::cout << "comment: " << boost::fusion::as_deque(item) << "\n";
    }
    for (auto& item : types.numbers) {
        std::cout << "number:  ";
        for (auto& g : item.groups)
            std::cout << boost::fusion::as_deque(g) << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: 100%
ok = 1
comment: (any char string here 0)
number:  (1 2 3) 
number:  (1 2 3) (4 5 6)
```

Comment: The meaning of the groups is that some elements have more than 3 points, but always in 3's. So 3, 6, 9, but not 4, 5, 7, 8, etc... Thanks, this worked.

Comment: Yeah we can help. The way to get it is by asking the question. Be sure to specify the goal functionally,  often best expressed with concrete examples